# non-mutually exclusive probability addition in SQL?

Tags: sql, probability

When two events, A and B, are non-mutually exclusive, the probability that A or B will occur is:
    P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)

For my problem, it's f(a,b)=a+b-a*b

Now if one is the calculate P(A or B or C) then one has to chain composition of that function as f(c, f(a,b))

Is there a way to do that efficiently in SQL without using a cursor when there are many rows to sum up?

*Update*

The complete answer based on @MikeP's answer:

```
SELECT 1-EXP(SUM(LOG(1.0-x))) FROM #foo
```

Thank you MikeP. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $P(A+B+C) = 1 - not(A) \cdot not(B) \cdot not(C)$ ?

Comment: Is this going to answer the full generality of the original question?

Comment: good question.  I was certainly more focused on the efficiency part than the extensibility part...

Comment: SELECT 1-EXP(SUM(LOG(1.0-x))) FROM #foo --perhaps